# RegEx in C#, getting the values without criterias

Tags: c#, regex

I am really terrible at RegEx, In the code below I only want the actual numbers between `SH:` and `, or end of line.` How can I achieve this?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Sandbox()
    {
        var regEx = new Regex(@"SH\:(.*?)(\,|\z)");
        var matches = regEx.Matches("Some Text|SH:0000000000,SH:1111111111");

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(match);

             /* Getting this
             SH:0000000000,
             SH:1111111111
             */

             /* Wanting this
             0000000000
             1111111111
             */
        }
    }
```

Comment: This pattern works: `SH:(\d+),*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your for loop as below

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also do this:

```
     var regEx = new Regex(@"SH\:(?<abc>.*?)(\,|\z)");
     Console.Out.WriteLine(match.Groups["abc"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"(?!SH:)\d+(?=\,|\z)?");
```

This will match just the numbers.